# Unable to find source for user defined functions in XSL

Tags: xslt, azure-functions

I have inherited support of a process that transforms some xml using xslt. I have been trying to find a way to debug locally, but I seem to be hung up on some custom functions that I cannot find the source of.

The namespaces in the xsl are defined as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" 
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"  
xmlns:user="urn:transformFunctions">
```

Further in the xsl, functions from that namespace are being referenced as follows:

```
<xsl:value-of select="user:PadString(TransactionHeader/SalesId,20,'padRight')"
```

While trying to debug locally I get nothing but blank output. If I remove the function calls and just select TransactionHeader/SalesId I get data as expected. The process runs fine as is when running in Production so I know the functions work.

I am very new to using xslt so please excuse if this is a basic question. The functions are not defined anywhere in the xsl itself, so where are they defined so I can use them while debugging locally?

Comment: So which XSLT processor do you use, how do you run it? If the functions are not defined in the XSLT then answer is that the functions are probably set up as extension functions with the processor's API and the XSLT is not the part to be changed or examined, it is the code running the transformation.

Comment: During my local testing I am just using the Chrome browser for the testing. As far as I understood, as long as the xml has a reference the xsl then all modern browsers should apply the transformations.
In the production environment it is running within an Azure Function, but again nowhere else in that functions are the custom user functions defined (that I can see)

Comment: "Modern" browsers tend to support the version 1.0 of XSLT from 1999 and that only supports XSLT processor specific ways to define extension functions, the use of `xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"` suggests for MSXML with JScript or VBScript or perhaps for .NET with C# or JScript. But browsers don't support that, other than IE.

Comment: Azure probably allows setting up extension objects and functions using the XslCompiledTransform API or provides some predefined functions set up that way.

Comment: So with .NET code https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/xslt-extension-objects is the relevant section to set up .NET code to be called from XSLT run with XslCompiledTransform.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I will have a read through that and see if I can figure out how this is all wired up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Martin was completely correct here. In my case there was an Azure function handling the processing of the xml. What I didn't notice originally was that it was calling a second function where the heavy lifting was taking place

```
XslCompiledTransform processor = new XslCompiledTransform();
            StringReader styleSheetReader = new StringReader(xsltStr);
            processor.Load(new XmlTextReader(styleSheetReader), new XsltSettings(), new XmlUrlResolver());
            XsltArgumentList argsList = new XsltArgumentList();
            StringReader sr = new StringReader(inputXML);
            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(sr, settings);
            
            var flatFile= "";
            argsList.AddExtensionObject("urn:transformFunctions", new XsltFunctions());
```